# Wordpress pagination doesn't display correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I added pagination to my blog template. My blog display three posts per page. I have problem with pagination.

So, pagination displays only when in url is `/?s=`.

e.g: http://localhost/sitename/?s=

Can anybody help me with this problem?

```
<?php
/*
*Template Name: Szablon wyszukiwarki
*Template Post Type: page, post
*/
?>
 
<?php 
get_header(); 
get_template_part('navigation');
?>
 
<div class="post-banner">
    <div class="post-title">
       <h1><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1> 
    </div>
</div>
   
 
    <?php $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    global $post;
 
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=>get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
    );
     
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="col-md">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img class="post-thumbnail" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium_large'); ?>"/>
        </a>
        <div class="post-details">
            <h6><?php echo get_the_date('j F Y'); ?></h6>
            <h6>Nazwa kategorii: <?php echo the_category(' '); ?> </h6>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <p>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; 
 
    posts_nav_link();
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
 
    
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

EDIT:
It works, but why I have to set '1' in this code:

```php
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
```

This code run without this parameter, so why?

```
    <?php
/*
*Template Name: Szablon wyszukiwarki
*Template Post Type: page, post
*/
?>
 
<?php 
get_header(); 
get_template_part('navigation');
?>
 
<div class="post-banner">
    <div class="post-title">
       <h1><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1> 
    </div>
</div>
   
<?php 

$query= new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'post', // your post type name
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('post_per_page'), // post per page
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
));

if($query->have_posts()) :
    while($query->have_posts())  : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img class="post-thumbnail" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium_large'); ?>"/>
            </a>
        <div class="post-details">
            <h6><?php echo get_the_date('j F Y'); ?></h6>
            <h6>Nazwa kategorii: <?php echo the_category(' '); ?> </h6>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <p>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div><?php
    endwhile;

    $total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
        
    }
    ?>    
<?php else :?>
<h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', ''); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `$arg` array i would do the following:

```php
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) //This would do the same thing as your ternary operator!
);
```

And then, instead of using `posts_nav_link`, i would pass the `max_num_pages` value to the `paginate_links` function like so:

```php
echo paginate_links(
  array(
    "total" => $myposts->max_num_pages
  )
);
```

Comment: thank You, your answer pointed out me a correct way, but i have a question, i written that in my post with question in 'edit' section.

Comment: It's not necessary to use that syntax. It only means, if there is no paged value in the url, then fetch the first page of the query. Again you don't have to use my syntax.